# Chartjs - Remove gap between bars

Tags: chart.js

I have the following graph and I want to remove the gap between each of the bars.

[image: stacked bar chart]

I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of the gap. `barPercentage` &  `categoryPercentage` are both set to `1.0`. I've tried playing with the border width, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. I want each bar to be right next to each with no spacing.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**Side Question**: The right border of the graph isn't drawing for some reason even though I have a padding set. Any ideas how to fix this too?

```
options: {
    layout: {
        padding: 10
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index'
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                display: false
            },
            barPercentage: 1.0,
            categoryPercentage: 1.0,
            gridLines: {

            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            // stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried barThickness property? check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/07pzys9t/2/

Comment: barThickness does seem to work, but it's not responsive. If the window size changes too much the gaps come back. I'd be interested in finding a responsive solution.

Comment: Is it browser dependent? I was seeing the same sort of thing in Firefox but in Chrome the bars fill the space nicely.